# Regex disabling escape key

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using the following code to try and only allow letters, numbers, backspace, space, dashes, and ampersands. I also want to "disabled" all other keys including the function keys (F1, F2, etc). The problem I am running in to is with the regex also disabling the escape key.

Can the same thing be achieved without using a regular expression?

This function is part of a live search feature, and I don't want the ajax request to be sent if on of the "prohibited" keys are pressed.

```
searchBox.keyup(function (e) { // LIVE SEARCH FUNCTION

        var functionKeysPressed = [112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123].indexOf(e.which) > -1;

        if (String.fromCharCode(e.which).match(/^[\w\x08]$/) && !functionKeysPressed) {

            // code to execute if key is allowed

        }

});
```

Comment: If you don't need IE9 support, you can use the pattern attribute for the most natural browser support: `<input pattern="[\w\x20\-&]*" />`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without a regex. Simple refer to `e.keyCode` instead of `e.which`:

```
if (e.keyCode == 27){
    //Esc Key pressed
}
```

for `onKeyUp`
keycode returns the Unicode keycode of the key that triggered the event.

You will find the keycodes here: 
http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

to exclude multiple keys, you could simply create an array and check if the keycode is blacklisted:

```
var blacklisted = [1,2,3,4,5];
if (blacklisted.indexOf(e.keyCode) == -1){
   //do something
}
```

Comment: Is it a good idea to have an array that large? If I go this route I would need to exclude quite a few keys.